# emacs sql mode could not save history

Tags: sql, emacs

below is my settings:

```
(defun my-sql-save-history-hook ()
(let ((lval 'sql-input-ring-file-name)
    (rval 'sql-product))
(if (symbol-value rval)
    (let ((filename
           (concat "~/.emacs.d/sql/"
                   (symbol-name (symbol-value rval))
                   "-history.sql")))
      (set (make-local-variable lval) filename)
      (set-default 'sql-input-ring-file-name filename))
  (error
   (format "SQL history will not be saved because %s is nil"
           (symbol-name rval))))))
```

and i describe the variable values:

```
    sql-input-ring-file-name's value is
    "~/.emacs.d/sql/mysql-history.sql"
    Original value was nil
    Local in buffer *SQL*; global value is the same.
```

and i have directory ~/.emacs.d/sql but do not have any file

my emacs version is 24.4.1

Comment: Why `set-default` instead  `setq`?  Also, the `(set (make-local-variable lval) filename)` seems unnecessary.  Please note that nothing will be saved until you close the connection (Control-D); if you kill the buffer or close emacs nothing will be saved.

Comment: great thanks, it works. another question, how to save the history when i kill the buffer. i would like it behave consistently with eshell or other history.

Comment: You need to call `comint-write-input-ring` in `kill-buffer-hook`

Comment: many thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting the answers above to work, but this works for me. The main change is `lval` and `kill-buffer-hook`

```
  (defun my-sql-save-history-hook ()
    (let ((lval 'comint-input-ring-file-name)
          (rval 'sql-product))
      (if (symbol-value rval)
          (let ((filename
                 (concat "~/.emacs.d/sql/"
                         (symbol-name (symbol-value rval))
                         "-history.sql")))
            (set (make-local-variable lval) filename))
        (error
         (format "SQL history will not be saved because %s is nil"
                 (symbol-name rval))))))

  (add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook 'my-sql-save-history-hook)
  (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'comint-write-input-ring)
```